# no such instruction: dd 0

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I got an error during the compilation of inline assembly code with c:

> `no such instruction:dd 0;`

Here's my code:

```
asm(
            ".data"
            "big: dd 0\n"
            ".text\n"               
            "mov out1,%eax\n"
            "add %eax,out2"     
        );
```

I'm trying to create a double word variable and later on I will assign `out2` (which is c variable) to it. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Does `dw` work? Try 4 of them.

Comment: Dw doesnt work,dword as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use this notation:

```
     .quad 0
```

The `.quad` directive allows you to declare a constant quad-word (8 bytes).

For more info, see the [GNU as](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.17/as/index.html) manual.

Comment: I'd have guessed `.long` for `dd`.

Comment: is it possible to represent hexadecimal values with long ?